# GraphicsPath start point

Tags: vb.net, graphicspath

Can the start point of a graphics be set?, say when i'm adding a string to a path then drawing that path the start point usually differ, so is there a way to set the start point??

also is there any way to read AI or SVG files using VB.net?

Thank you.

Comment: This would be great for a **Google search**. Anyways the answers, yes and yes. Since SVG files are XML you can use the standard XML classes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're wanting to do is apply a transformation to your Graphics object, here is an example.

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 0, 0, 100, 100)
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(10.0F, 10.0F)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 0, 0, 100, 100)
End Sub
```

Notice that once we call TranslateTransform all subsequent calls to draw operations will be offset by 10px from the top left. You can revert this transformation by calling e.Graphics.ResetTransform()